# Mongoose do not validate on update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I currently have a Mongoose Schema with validation:

```
assignmentID: {
  type: Number,
  validate: {
    validator: function(v) {
      if (!v) {
        return false;
      }

      return Assignment.findById(v)
        .then(assignmentDoc => {
          if (!assignmentDoc) {
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          return false;
        });
    },
    message: "Invalid assignment ID."
  }
}
```

The validator works perfectly. However, it is executed when I update a document via `.save()`.

Is it possible to change it so the validation executes only when the document is created and not when the document is updated?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set `validateBeforeSave` to false:

```
var schema = new Schema({ name: String });
schema.set('validateBeforeSave', false);
schema.path('name').validate(function (value) {
    return v != null;
});
var M = mongoose.model('Person', schema);
var m = new M({ name: null });
m.validate(function(err) {
    console.log(err); // Will tell you that null is not allowed.
});
m.save(); // Succeeds despite being invalid
```

reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#validateBeforeSave